# async function has old state React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux

I am working on a React project where user can upload and remove photos in projects. After Uploading new image it should be visible to user only if corresponding projectis selected. The solution is fairly simple to check

```
if 
(selectedProject.projectID=== imageMetadata.projectID)
```

where

- **selectedProject.projectID:** Id of currently selected project( Comming from
  Redux Store )
- **imageMetadata.projectID:** Id of project to which uploaded image belongs.

All of this is being done inside an **async** function and the problem we are facing is that even after **selectedAlbum.albumID** is changed everywhere else, this function still has its old value. Is it because the function is async?

This is my code:

```
 let projectId = selectedProject.projectID;
 const responses = await Promise.all(
   filesToUpload.map( async (file) => {
     let res = await imageStoreApiHandler.uploadPhoto(file, projectId);
     notifyUploadProgress(count++, total, notifcationKey);
     if (res.status === 200) {
       let imageMetadata: any = res.data[0];
       if (selectedProject.projectID === imageMetadata.projectID) {
         addImage(imageMetadata);
       }
     }
     return res;
   }));
```

Comment: Are you doing it inside an action?

Comment: doing inside onClick event, what do you mean by action ?

Comment: A redux action :). Probably need some more code to solve the problem

Comment: Edited and pasted complete function above. What is causing the issue ? Can you provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a closure problem where the uploadhandler keeps caching the first function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Maybe write a function which will return a promise all array based on the parameters current project id.